# Import model from app to main django project

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have made my website in django.
There is one main project folder names django_project and one blogging project names blogging.
All the blogs i have created are stored in the model of blogging folder.
If i want to show a list of all blogs in home page how can i import the models in django_project folder and show list of blogs there as well.

Comment: show the blogs in admin page or in some view? If in the admin page, you just import  **from blogging.models import model_name** , in the views also like this..

Comment: Please provide the project structure

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the Views of the blogging app and then include your blogging app URLs in the django_project URLs